# Getting errors after about 30 mins of processing Flow Direction using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, dem, error-010067, flow-direction, error-010429

I'm trying to process the flow direction from a filled DEM using ArcGIS 10.2.2 and I get these errors after about 30 mins of processing, every time, no matter what I try. I tried changing the raster's format (form GRID to TIFF), the projection, the Drive it's save on, etc.

```
ERROR 010429: Error in GRID IO: S_VXfer: Read error.  
ERROR 010213: Error in reading raster [path].  
ERROR 010429: Error in GRID IO: S_VXfer: Write error.
ERROR 010429: Error in GRID IO: S_VXfer: Write error. 2- Another person or application is accessing this directory   
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to executed (FlowDirection).
```

[image]

Can anyone help?

**EDIT : It works when I reduce the processing extent to calculated the flow direction on a small part of my DEM, but it won't work for the whole layer.**

Comment: Are you working on a network drive?

Comment: ^What he said.  Also, check your task manager to be sure there are no other ArcGIS processes running in the background that did not close properly.

Comment: I am not working on a network drive and no other processes are running.

Comment: It works when I reduce the processing extent to calculated the flow direction on a small part of my DEM, but it won't work for the whole layer.

Comment: How big are we taking about? Have you checked to see what the file size of any temporary files being created?

Comment: Just ran into this error, for me it was because I was processing large files and I had run out of disk space. Kinda makes sense given IO is mentioned in the error messages. I believe ArcGIS just throws all the errors it can when this issue arises, which makes troubleshooting that much harder.